# Why in physics the elementary work is written as $\delta W$ instead of $dW$?

Tags: derivatives, differential-forms

Why an elementary work is written $\delta W$ instead of $dW$? For example, it's often written $$\delta W=F\cdot dr$$ if $dr$ is the elementary displacement. Why don't we write as usual $dW=F\cdot dr$ ? I saw an answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65724/difference-between-delta-d-and-delta) but it doesn't really answer to the question (at my opinion). By the way, since at the end $W_{AB}=\int_A^B \delta W$, I really don't understand this $\delta W$. Is there mathematically a sense ?

Comment: Some thermodynamics books write this as a d with a small slash through the top (I can't do this easily in MathJax).

Comment: @Ted, one could try moving a \bar horizontally: $\newcommand{\dbar}{d\hspace{-0.35em}\bar{}}\dbar W$

Comment: @rych: Thanks. Too high and too wide, but I know I could design it if I really wanted to make the effort. :)

Answer (score 5):

The notation $\delta W$ rather than $\mathrm{d} W$ aims to underline that work (like heat) is an *improper differential*, i.e. its integral depends crucially on the integration path taken.

- In physical terms, the work done on a system will not only depend on the initial and final condition of the system, but on the transformation chosen to drive the system from its initial to its final condition.
- In more mathematical terms, an inexact differential cannot be expressed as the the gradient of another function, making an integral of that differential path-dependent.

I found the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential) on the topic quite helpful; any good textbook on thermodynamics will discuss this, for example Schwabl's [Statistical Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540323430).

Answer (score 1):

In physical literature the symbol $d W$ is used to indicate an [exact differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms), and $\delta W$ is used because, in general, the infinitesimal work $\delta W=F \cdot d\vec r$ is not an exact differential form. It is an exact form if the force $F$ is  conservative, so, in this case we write $\delta W=dW$.